# ASP.NET 5 on IIS Express is not refreshed automatically when js files are added

Tags: asp.net-core, dnx, kestrel-http-server

I am running an ASP.NET 5 solution in Visual studio and I add java script files in a bundle like that:

```
<script asp-src-include="~/app/**/*.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
```

Now when I change a file, then it works properly and the hash string is changed and it gets updated, but when I add a file to the folder nothing really happens, I have to kill IIS Express and run again. Is there a way to fix it or it's the way how static file middleware / razor behaves? (Just with the files it knows of from the first time)

Comment: Could you include the code of `Configure` from your `Startup.cs` or better the whole `Startup.cs`?

Comment: It's quite a lot there really, is there something of particular importance? I thought it can't affect this...

Comment: The list of included middleware components and especially *the order* of calls is important because it defines the pipeline. If you write that . You can try to move the call `app.UseStaticFiles();` at the top (direct after `UseIISPlatformHandler`) or temporary disable as more as possible other middleware components, just testing adding of new js files and opening it directly in web browser by full URL.

Comment: I don't have much middleware really, I have only 4 in this order: 1. IISPlatformHandler 2. StaticFiles 3. UseRequestLocalization 4. UseMvc. And static files is right after iis platform handler.